# simple calculation not working for some reason

Tags: c#, .net, percentage

Alright, I'm trying to calculate the percentage of two values. This should be really simple but for some weird reason it's not working. I'm too tired/dumb to figure it out.
Here's my code, it keeps returning 0, i checked the values while debugging and with FilesCompleted being 295 and TotalFilesCount being 25002 the returnvalue var is just 0, it should be 1 already.

```
private int CalculatePercentComplete(int FilesCompleted, int TotalFilesCount)
        {
            int returnvalue = (FilesCompleted / TotalFilesCount) * 100;

            if (returnvalue > 100 || returnvalue < 1) return 1;
            else return returnvalue;
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> i checked the values while debugging and with FilesCompleted being 295 and TotalFilesCount being 25002 the returnvalue var is just 0, it should be 1 already.

No, because all the arithmetic is being done with integers. So first this expression is evaluated:

```
(FilesCompleted / TotalFilesCount)
```

That's 295 / 25002. The result of that *integer* arithmetic is 0... and when you then multiply it by 100, you've *still* got 0. The simplest fix is just to do the multiplication first:

```
int returnvalue = (FilesCompleted * 100) / TotalFilesCount;
```

Note that that will overflow if `FilesCompleted` is greater than `int.MaxValue / 100`. You could fix that by either doing everything in floating point arithmetic:

```
int returnvalue = (int)((FilesCompleted * 100.0) / TotalFilesCount);
```

... or by using `long` integer arithmetic:

```
int returnvalue = (int)((FilesCompleted * 100L) / TotalFilesCount);
```

Neither of these are necessary if you don't expect to have an insane number of files, of course. (You're fine up to 42 million files...)

As a side note, your parameter names violate .NET naming conventions. They should be camelCased - `totalFilesCount` and `filesCompleted`.

Comment: Hmh interesting, well that's something I did not yet know.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
int returnvalue = (int)(((double)FilesCompleted / TotalFilesCount) * 100);
```

What this is doing

1. Converting `int` FilesCompleted to `double`. For eg if its 295, then this will convert it into 295.0 so that division happens in double.

   There is no need to convert `TotalFilesCount` to double also as divison of double by integer (or integer by double) returns a double.
2. So the returned double result is 0.011799056075513958 which is multipled by 100
3. So the retunred result is 1.1799056075513958 which is finally converted to int which returns 1

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, simple error, when doing diversions with int, the answer will be an int. Your answer would be between 0 and 1 so rounded down it is 0 (int).

Use:

```
int returnvalue = (int)((FilesCompleted / (double)TotalFilesCount) * 100);
```

To make your calculation use a double for the fractional number and then multiply that by 100 and cast that to an int.

Comment: My bad, fixed it, problem with the ()

Answer (score 1):

The `FilesCompleted/TotalFilesCount` returns 0.01 which in int format is 0, try `FilesCompleted*100/TotalFilesCount`!