# C# Math division not correct

Tags: c#, math, division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288904/division-returns-zero)
>   [simple calculation not working for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329042/simple-calculation-not-working-for-some-reason)

Why is this:

```
int prozent = (totalkcals / 2000) * 100;
```

returning 0?

totalkcals is in this case 567, I double-checked it.

Answer (score 6):

This is because of [integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the **absolute value of the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the absolute value of the quotient of the two operands**. The result is zero or positive when the two operands have the same sign and zero or negative when the two operands have opposite signs

Answer (score 3):

Its because of Integer division.

```
double prozent = ((double)totalkcals / 2000) * 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

567 / 2000 = 0.2835, which when cast to an int (as specified by your data type) becomes zero.  0 * 100 = 0.

So:  `double prozent = ((double)totalcals / 2000.0) * 100.0;`

Answer (score 1):

Its because its an integer calculation, so the operation from (totalkcals / 2000) returns 0;