# How to change cell colors dynamically in datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

How can i change datagridview colors in cell 5 dynamically?

Example: [image]

2nd row last cell value is 29508,  I want 2nd row cell color to be green.

4th row last cell value is 2016, 4th row cell color should be orange.

Here codes:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    XDocument x = XDocument.Load(@"../../Data/gemi1/gemi1s1.xml");
    var nodes = x.Descendants("item").Where(x => x.Element("id").Value.ToString() == row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    int barhesap;
    barhesap = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Value);
    foreach (XElement x5 in nodes)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) <= barhesap / 10)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) <= barhesap / 8)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) <= barhesap / 6)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) <= barhesap / 4)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) <= barhesap / 2)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) <= barhesap / 1.5)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) <= barhesap / 1.2)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) <= barhesap / 1)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            row.Cells[5].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

We re taken barhesap's value in 7th column cell.
Its here:

```
private void ekle_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Add button with save
{
    int veriid;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"../../Data/gemi1/gemi1id.xml");
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/rootElement/id");
    veriid = Convert.ToInt32(node.InnerText);
    txtID.Text = veriid.ToString();
    int barsonuc = 0;
    int sayi = Convert.ToInt32(periyot_sayi_txt.Text);

    if (periyot_aralik_cb.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lütfen bakım periyodu için bir seçenek seçin", "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    else if (periyot_aralik_cb.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        barsonuc = sayi * 1;
    }
    else if (periyot_aralik_cb.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        barsonuc = sayi * 24;
    }
    else if (periyot_aralik_cb.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        barsonuc = sayi * 168;
    }
    else if (periyot_aralik_cb.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        barsonuc = sayi * 720;
    }
    else if (periyot_aralik_cb.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        barsonuc = sayi * 8640;
    }
    ilerleme_bar.Maximum = barsonuc;
    string sonsonuc = barsonuc.ToString();
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
    string file_path = @"../../Data/gemi1/gemi1s1.xml";
    xDoc = XDocument.Load(file_path);
    XElement rootElement = xDoc.Root;
    XElement newElement = new XElement("item",
    new XElement("id", txtID.Text),
    new XElement("parca_adi", parca_adi_txt.Text),
    new XElement("son_bakim", son_bakim_txt.Text),
    new XElement("periyot_sayi", periyot_sayi_txt.Text),
    new XElement("periyot_aralik", periyot_aralik_cb.SelectedItem),
    new XElement("bar_max", sonsonuc),
    new XElement("pa_id", periyot_aralik_cb.SelectedIndex),
    new XElement("ilerleme", sonsonuc));
    rootElement.Add(newElement);
    xDoc.Save(file_path);
    // ID provider value
    string file_pathid = @"../../Data/gemi1/gemi1id.xml";
    XDocument id = XDocument.Load(file_pathid);
    XElement node1 = id.Element("rootElement").Elements("id").FirstOrDefault();
    if (node1 != null)
    {
        node1.SetElementValue("id", (Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text) + 1).ToString());
    }
    id.Save(file_pathid);
    yukle();
}
```

But 1st foreach code block not working and cells still same color. How can I change it?

Comment: Have you use the debugger to make sure that one of the `if` is true, and that a color is set?

Comment: I'd also say to be careful with the math, if you're doing integer division with `barhesap / x`: in int terms, 15/10 and 15/8 give the same result; 1

Comment: can you give me an example ? @CaiusJard

Comment: I don't believe I said anything exampleworthy?

Comment: I think the problem is the condition of the if statement. As Caius Jard said, barhesap / x may have the same calculation result.

Comment: i understand @CaiusJard thx .

Comment: For the future, you're more likely to get an answer if you can share a [mcve] showing the **minimal** amount of code to reproduce the problem.  In this case, we would need to see a ***specific value of `barhesap`*** that demonstrates the problem.  You show code that extracts `barhesap` from some XML but you don't include the XML so we can't reproduce the problem.  But better to show us a literal value for `barhesap` than the XML since the LINQ-to-XML code isn't really relevant.  See: [ask].

Comment: Have the comments by @CaiusJard solved the problem for you?  Can the question be closed, e.g. as a duplicate of [How can I divide two integers to get a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661028/3744182) or [Why does integer division in C# return an integer and not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851273/3744182) or [What's wrong with this division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704702/3744182) or [simple calculation not working for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12329042/3744182)?